# Installing .Net Framework Error: 0x800f080c Feature name netfx3 is unknown

Tags: windows, windows-10, troubleshooting, .net-framework, .net-3.5

When I run the .Net Framework 3.5 Installer I get the following error: Windows couldn't complete the requested changes. When I try to enable .Net framework in the command prompt I get the following error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:netfx3 /all 
/limitaccess

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.18362.1

Image Version: 10.0.18362.86


Error: 0x800f080c

Feature name netfx3 is unknown.
A Windows feature name was not recognized.
Use the /Get-Features option to find the name of the feature in the image 
and try the command again.

The DISM log file can be found at
```

[C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Avqi6Pt1BGP3gbsEeBSOAHC3yj5l1A)

[When I go to Windows Features, my list looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xqdc.png)

[My whole .Net Framework is completely gone.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPicj.png)

[This is how registry looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWJkj.png)

My applications like paint.net, discord, UDK, UE4 and Windows Troubleshooter don't work.

I tried to install .net Framework using Server Manager, bu that also requires .Net Framework

UT3 Editor works though :)

Here is the error I'm receiving:

```
PaintDotNet.exe - .NET Framework Initialization Error

To run this application, you first must install one of the following versions of the .NET Framework:
```

v4.0

Contact your application publisher for instructions about obtaining the appropriate version of the .NET Framework.

OK

And here are my specs:

```
⌘ Windows 10

Microsoft Windows Version 1903 (OS Build 18885.1001) @ 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved

The Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview Operating System and its user interface are protected by trademark and other pending or existing intellectual property rights in the United States and other countries/regions.

Evaluation copy. Expires 08/01/20 00-41
```

To add more important information, in "Control Panel\System and Security\System" System type is "64-bit Operating System, x64 based processor"

**Edit:** some of my issues have been fixed because Framework 4.8 automatically reinstalled itself by an update, .net 1.1 and 2 are install-able, so it's just waiting until the apps I use add .Net 4.8 Support, Thank you all for your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had major issues with Windows 10 Pro 1909.

**The solution was to move to the Windows Insider Program (Settings\Update&Security\Windows Insider Program).**

That upgraded the computer to the preview version. Immediately after booting it asks me to install .NET 2/3.5, which fixed all the issues.

Note that I tried to applied the other solution in this question. I also applied an in-place upgrade to build 1909 and many other options with no success.

My plan is to keep the computer in the insider program for 6 months and then moving back to "general population".

Answer (score 1):

Same issue Windows 10 Enterprise 1909 (update from 1903):

[image]

DISM log:

```
2019-12-06 22:09:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=13756 TID=14532 Processing the top level command token(enable-feature). - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ValidateCmdLine
2019-12-06 22:09:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=13756 TID=14532 Attempting to route to appropriate command handler. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2019-12-06 22:09:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=13756 TID=14532 Routing the command... - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2019-12-06 22:09:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=13756 TID=14532 Encountered the option "featurename" with value "NetFx3" - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetPackagesFromCommandLine
2019-12-06 22:09:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=13756 TID=14532 Encountered an unknown option "featurename" with value "NetFx3" - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetPackagesFromCommandLine
2019-12-06 22:09:00, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=13756 TID=14532 Failed to get the Update through CBS. - CDISMPackage::Internal_OpenFeature(hr:0x800f080c)
2019-12-06 22:09:00, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=13756 TID=14532 Failed to get the underlying CBS Feature - CDISMPackage::OpenFeature(hr:0x800f080c)
2019-12-06 22:09:00, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=13756 Feature name NetFx3 is unknown. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetFeaturesFromCommandLine(hr:0x800f080c)
2019-12-06 22:09:00, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=13756 TID=14532 Unknown features were specified on the command-line. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetFeaturesFromCommandLine(hr:0x800f080c)
2019-12-06 22:09:00, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=13756 TID=14532 Failed to get the Feature List from the command line. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ProcessFeatureChange(hr:0x800f080c)
2019-12-06 22:09:00, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=13756 TID=14532 Failed while processing command enable-feature. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x800f080c)
2019-12-06 22:09:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=13756 TID=14532 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
```

Windows repair and installing .Net 4.8 makes no difference in my case.

Solution:

Install the the following packages manually

[image]

using DISM.EXE like:

```
Dism.exe /online /add-package /packagepath:c:\Windows\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-NetFx3-OC-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.18362.1.mum
```

After all 6 missing packages was installed adding the netfx3 feature works just fine even without reboot!

[image]