# Error: 0x800f080c trying to install WSL

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-error-reporting

I was trying to install Linux on my computer using WSL for a programming class I'll have in college that requires Linux.

I opened PowerShell as admin and typed "wsl --install" but it returned the following error: "Error: 0x800f080c".

I did everything (except reinstalling windows) from this website: https://www.saintlad.com/error-0x800f080c-on-windows-10/, but nothing worked.

In step 2 on this website ("Enabling 3.5 .NET Framework via Windows Features."), I even got the same error:

[image]

Is there a way to fix that isn't Clean Installing Windows?

Comment: Try [`Dism.exe /online /add-package /packagepath:c:\Windows\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-NetFx3-OC-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.18362.1.mum`](https://superuser.com/questions/1430720/installing-net-framework-error-0x800f080c-feature-name-netfx3-is-unknown) to verify if you are able to install .NET Framework 3.5.  This is a test to narrow down the cause of the error you have received.

Comment: I assume you have enabled Hardware Virtualization?

Answer (score 0):

**(A)** Did you enable WSL (Programs and Features, Windows Features)?

**(B)** Is .NET fully up to date and working (again Windows Features)?

Look at this Microsoft Article involving .NET Framework:
["Error: 0x800f080c".](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/0x800f080c/06945f39-36ec-4eeb-b25f-6b2b3505fc5b)

In the link you posted in your question, DISM / SFC was included.  That did not work for you (according to your question).

Therefore, there is some chance you will have to reinstall Windows if nothing works.

Remember to back up your data, documents and email first to a USB drive so you can recover them later.

**(C)** WSL is for entering Linux commands and is not a Virtual Machine App.

Can you install Linux as a Virtual Machine?  I do this with VMware but Hyper-V works too (again Windows Features to enable Hyper-V). I am sure you will find a Virtual Machine better and more flexible.

VMware, Hyper-V and its variants (likely including WSL) requires Hardware Virtualization to be enabled in BIOS.

Comment: I tried to enable it on "Turn windows features on and off", but the option for WSL didn't appear.

Comment: It should appear in Windows Feature as Windows Subsystem for Linux (so not just WSL).  I checked my own Windows 10 system.  If truly not there, you may (as I noted in my answer) be faced with reinstalling Windows.

Comment: Yeah, "Windows Subsystem for Linux" is not there. If I reinstall windows do I lose any of my data stored on the computer?

Comment: You will need to back up your data to a USB Drive prior to reinstalling Windows. I made a more complete note in my answer

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it then

Comment: I have given all the information you need, so you may wish to acknowledge my answer.